# having same amount of value in each php array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2015-07-21
                [1] => 2015-07-22
                [2] => 2015-07-23
                [3] => 2015-07-24
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => 3389 Remote Desktop
        [data] => Array
            (
                [2015-07-21] => 37
                [2015-07-22] => 21
                [2015-07-23] => 38
                [2015-07-24] => 14
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => 80 HTTP
        [data] => Array
            (
                [2015-07-21] => 22
                [2015-07-22] => 2
                                   // <- here is missing [2015-07-23] => 0
                                   // <- here is missing [2015-07-24] => 0
            )

    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [name] => 21 FTP
        [data] => Array
            (
                                   // <- here is missing [2015-07-21] => 0                                         
                [2015-07-22] => 1
                [2015-07-23] => 20
                                   // <- here is missing [2015-07-24] => 0
            )

    )

)
```

What function can achieve that the missing elements are added? I have so far something along the lines:

```
$newarray = array();
$count = count($arr[0][data]);
foreach($arr as $key => $subarr) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
        if (in_array($i, $subarr)) $newarray[$key][$i - 1] = $i;
        else $newarray[$key][$i - 1] = 0;
    }
}
```

which works partially and gives:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 0
        [2] => 0
        [3] => 0
    )

[3389 Remote Desktop] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 0
        [2] => 0
        [3] => 0
    )

[80 HTTP] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 0
        [2] => 0
        [3] => 0
    )

[21 FTP] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 0
        [2] => 0
        [3] => 0
    )
)
```

but I need to have exactly the same structure as the initial array. Any help welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$res = [$array[0]];
// make  default array with all zeros
$default = array_combine($array[0]['data'], array_fill(0,count($array[0]['data']),0));
// make new array changing default values with present

for($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++ ) 
  $res[] = ['name' => $array[$i]['name'], 
            'data' => array_replace($default, $array[$i]['data'])];

print_r($res);
```

Comment: That is working nicely but has one flaw: the new structure of the array is not the same like in the initial one.

Comment: small issue for info: the inital $array[0]['data'] array has the wrong format compared to the original one ;)

Comment: i dont see the difference in print_r output :(   https://eval.in/407297  Maybe you help me understand and i will correct

Comment: In the answer here you have $res = [$array[0]['data']] while in the example $res = [$array[0]]; . Now all works.

Comment: @domi771  sorry my bad. move only foreach block

Answer (score 0):

If you have always defined all dates on first element, then you can do it like that:

```
$data = array(); // your array
$allDates = $data[0]['data'];
for($i=1; $i<count($data); $i++)
{
    foreach($allDates as $reqDate)
    {
        if(!array_key_exists($reqDate, $data[$]['data'])
        {
            $data[$]['data'][$reqDate] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, the dates are always defined on the first element. I get with your code so far a typo $data[$]['data'])) missing ) there. Are you sure its $data[$] and not $data[$i] ?

Comment: with both of my corrections above this works perfect. Only problem remaining is that the inserted dates with 0 values are not in the correct order.